# JQuery function distorts image. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css

See for yourself. I can't figure out if it's even possible to get rid of that weird colored border. The point of this code is to be able to rotate an image and change the color of it at the same time. The way the code is, the color and angle of the image can easily be coded to be dynamic. This code uses a png image that is white, but has a transparency layer in the shape of the paw print. This way when you edit the background color, it changes the color of the image. It would work great if it were not for the weird border that gets added to the image... notice if you remove the rotate functionality, there is no annoying border.

Including JQuery 1.8.2, here is the HTML/CSS code:

CSS:

```
.image {
display: inline-block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color: blue;


transform: rotate(30deg);


}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="icon"></span>​
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this: `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` solved it for me

Comment: But this works only for -webkit library, isn't there a solution also for other browsers?

Comment: Here's the code for other browsers. Supposedly this should work, but I'm still getting the "border" on Firefox, even though on Chrome it seems to be fixed.
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;

Comment: Maybe try something like `outline: 1px solid transparent;` - i'm not sure this is possible to make completely cross-browser compatible

Answer (score 1):

The paw is created by making its area transparent in the png and setting the background to red and the surrounding area white.

My suggestion, do the opposite. Fill the paw with red in your png and leave the space around it transparent. At least in your fiddle there will no longer be a red line around it as the background color will be set to white.